ModuleNotFoundError when importing HuggingFaceLLM from llama_index.core.llms.huggingface
I’m trying to import HuggingFaceLLM using the following line of code:
from llama_index.core.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceLLM

I know that llamaindex keeps updating, and previously this import worked with:
from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceLLM

However, I have tried all possible ways but keep getting the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.core.llms.huggingface'

Has anyone faced this issue or knows how to fix it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Install this
pip install llama-index-llms-huggingface

And then import the library as
from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceLLM

You can look into the https://pypi.org/project/llama-index-llms-huggingface/
